# How to select columns that contain infinite values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with many columns, and I want to check if any column contains infinite values, using `dplyr`. How to select columns that contain infinite values in dplyr?

Comment: Including negative infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select any number of columns that contain infinite values in `dplyr`, use `where` inside `select` to check if `any` value within each column evaluates true on `is.infinite`:

```
# first, create a dataframe that has a column with Inf values
data <- iris |> 
  mutate(Sepal.Width = Sepal.Width/0)

data |>
  select(where(~ any(is.infinite(.))))
```